# “A lot of noise” vs. “a lot of noises”

Tags: nouns, singular-vs-plural, countability

I learn English at [this file](https://aguswuryanto.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/english-modul-for-sma.pdf), and I have a question. I have the sentence

> **"Jet engines make a lot of noise."**

(Page 6)

Why is it ***a lot of noise*** instead of ***a lot of noises***?

Please help with clear description.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*A lot of noise* means loud noise.  One predominant type of noise, at high volume.

*A lot of noise**s*** means many different sounds.

*The jet airplane makes lots of noise.*  (Or *The jet airplane makes a lot of noise.*)

*My 50 year old truck makes lots of noises.* (The engine grumbles, the fan belt squeaks, the brakes screech, etc.)